# Laravel and Redis implementation

Tags: laravel, redis, stackexchange.redis, laravel-10, software-distribution

I want to execute the below Redis query in Laravel. Can anyone please let me know how we can achieve this?

```
FT.AGGREGATE leads:index "@createdAt:[1638300000 1638400000]"
GROUPBY 1 @leadBy
REDUCE COUNT_DISTINCT 1 @leadId AS performance_count
```

I tried like this, but I'm getting an error

> Command `RAWCOMMAND` is not a registered Redis command

Code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class CommonController extends BaseController
{
    public function checkRedisWorking(){
        $query = 'FT.AGGREGATE leads:index "@createdAt:[1638200000 1638400000]" GROUPBY 1 @leadBy   REDUCE COUNT_DISTINCT 1 @leadId AS performance_count';

        // Get the underlying Predis client
        $result = Redis::rawCommand('FT.AGGREGATE', 'leads:index', $query);

        // Display the result
        var_dump($result);
    }
}
```